# How do I get google maps style to work on mobile platforms?

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, mobile, styles

I'm trying to add a style to my google map. But when opening the page in browsers, the style sometimes does not load, and sometimes it does.

This is one of the problems, but i'm guessing there might be some relation with the next problem:

When opening the page on mobile platforms (tried android chrome, ios safari and windows phone IE) the style never loads.

I'm sorry if this post is not correct or by the standars in any way. This is my first time posting at stackoverflow.

Would appreciate the help so much!

```
function initialize() {

var mapOptions = {
zoom: 13,
};
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapCanvas'),
  mapOptions);



if(navigator.geolocation) {
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
  var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                                   position.coords.longitude);

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    map: map,
    position: pos,
    content: 'This is you'
  });

  map.setCenter(pos);
}, function() {
  handleNoGeolocation(true);
});
} else {
handleNoGeolocation(false);
}
}

var styles = [
{
"elementType": "labels.text.fill",
"stylers": [
  { "invert_lightness": true },
  { "gamma": 0.01 },
  { "hue": "#e500ff" }
]
},{
"elementType": "geometry",
"stylers": [
  { "hue": "#00fff7" }
]
},{
"stylers": [
  { "gamma": 0.78 },
  { "visibility": "on" },
  { "invert_lightness": true }
]
}
]


function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
if (errorFlag) {
var content = 'This is not where you are, right?';
} else {
var content = 'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.';
}

var options = {
map: map,
position: new google.maps.LatLng(60, 105),
content: content
};

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(options);
map.setOptions({styles: styles});
map.setCenter(options.position);

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

And then the HTML is:

```
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
<link href='css/style.css' rel='stylesheet' />

<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=true"></script>
<script src='js/main.js'></script>

<style>
body {
    margin:0; padding:0;
}

#mapCanvas {
    position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%;
    z-index: 1;
}


</style>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">

<div id="mapCanvas"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

These is the sample how to implement Google map

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html> 
        <head> 
          <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
          <title>Google Maps Multiple Markers</title> 
          <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" 
                  type="text/javascript"></script>
          <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
        </head> 
        <body>
          <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>     
        </body>
        </html>
```

In main.js

```
    var locations = [
              ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
              ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
              ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
              ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
              ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
            ];

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
              zoom: 10,
              center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            });

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

            var marker, i;

            for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
              marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
                map: map
              });

              google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                return function() {
                  infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                  infowindow.open(map, marker);
                }
              })(marker, i));
            }
          </script>
```